# How do I install a network printer that needs a user name and password?

Tags: printing

The printer is a Ricoh 8100S, which does has a [Linux driver](https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Ricoh/Ricoh-Pro_8100S). The university gave me documentation for installing the printer on MacOS and Windows, but nothing about Linux. The Mac instructions give the host name and IP address:

```
Hostname: copier.dept.university.edu
IP Address: XXX.XXX.XX.XX
```

[image: first step]

[image: second step]

[image: third step]

I didn't include some of the steps here because they just involve clicking through the menus. **Basically, when I configure the printer, I authenticate with my university username and password, and a "lock code" that I use to access the jobs on the printer itself.**

What is the analog of these instructions for a Linux systemIs there a way to install this printer through cups? Cups version is 2.2.1-8.

Comment: You can look though the CUPS configuration on OS X to see if there's any clue there.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/database/ricohfaq#what-are-usercodes-how-do-i-use-usercodes-under-linux) seems to document a way to configure the user code:

Good luck!

Comment: How do I add the printer and tell it to use a username and password, *in addition* to the user code? The username and password are different from my local user account. The `-U` flag on `lpadmin` appears to govern what *local* user account should be used to add the printer, not the user account that is  used to authenticate with the printer itself.